# insert data to arry from DB and print json

Tags: php

I want to show the result like this: -

[{"date:Jul-25","value:1"},{"date:Jul-24","value:0"},{"date:Jul-23","value:1"}]

But it show like this:

[{"value":"1"},{"Date":"Jul-25"},{"value":"0"},{"Date":"Jul-24"}]

Please help.

```
function get_new_member()
{

global $db_conn;
$data = array();
for ($i=0; $i<= 14; $i++)
{
    $key = date('M-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-$i, date('Y')));
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-$i,date("Y")));

    $sql=<<<EOF
    SELECT count(*) as count
    FROM crm_members
    WHERE REGISTER_DATE ='{$date1}' 
 EOF;

    $sql_res = mysqli_query($db_conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res);
    $numRows = $row['count'];

    $data[]['value'] = $numRows;
    $data[]['Date'] = $key;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

try doing:

```
$data[$i]['value'] = $numRows;
$data[$i]['Date'] = $key;
```

this will assign your values under same array variable

Answer (score 0):

You have another Array in each recod try this

> ```
>     $data = array('value'=>$numRows,'Date'=>$key);
> ```